# Countifs Google Sheets on multiple columns: search for dates

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I need to make a countifs function work, it has to match the number of orders received from a specific country during a month.

I'm trying to make a COUNTIFS function work: In sheet 1 I have a table containing a column with dates, one with order numbers and one with the country.

| Column A | Column B | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | ord #1 | Italy |
| 04/01/2023 | ord #2 | USA |
| 05/01/2023 | ord #3 | Italy |
| 09/01/2023 | ord #4 | USA |

I need to fill another table in sheet 2 where the countries are listed in rows and months in columns and I need the function to count how many orders arrived on that month from that country.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Italy | 2 |
| USA | 2 |

I tried with this function:

```
=COUNTIFS('ORDINI SHOPIFY'!A:C;"Italy";'ORDINI SHOPIFY'!A:C;"*/01/2023*")
```

But the result is "0" for each cell. I'm not used to Google Sheets, I usually work with Excel and maybe there is something in the syntax that I didn't get yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your column `A` is text:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"Italy",A:A,"*/01/2023")
```

Result:

[image]

If your column `A` is actual date:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum((C:C="Italy")*(month(A:A)=1)*(year(A:A)=2023)))
```

Result:

[image]

Adapt to your ranges and formula separator.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two options to generate the full chart with QUERY:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"SELECT C,COUNT(B) WHERE A is not null group by C pivot MONTH(A)+1",1)
```

[image]

Or, if you need the full format of date, you can previously "convert" Column A to MM-YYYY (or as you need it):

```
=QUERY({INDEX(TEXT(A:A,"MM-YYYY")),B:C},"SELECT Col3,COUNT(Col2) WHERE Col2 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1",1)
```

[image]